# multiple chart output, each with multpile data, one in reverse order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a chart for each ID (column 1) plotting foo and bar by dayt on each chart, and bar needs to be on an inverted axis...

my data has form

```
ID <- rep(6:10, times=5)
foo <-rnorm(n=25, mean=0, sd=1)
bar <-rnorm(n=25, mean=10, sd=1)
dayt <-rnorm(n=25, mean= 1, sd=1)
df <-data.frame(ID,dat,x,y)
```

I have no idea where to go from here except that I know ggplot2 allows multiple objects to be added to a chart easily...

I am trying something like this

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
require(gridExtra)

pl <- dlply(df, .(ID), function(dat) {
 ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = dayt, y = foo)) + geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + xlab("x-label") + ylab("y-label") + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
})


ml <- do.call(marrangeGrob, c(pl, list(nrow = 5, ncol = 1)))
ggsave("my_plots.pdf", ml, height = 8, width = 11, units = "in")
```

but cant figure out how to add the second data to each plot as well as invert the axis...

any help would be great!

thanks

zr

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a simple scatter plot, with multiple charts for each ID and a reversed Y axis.

If you want to create one plot with multiple charts for each ID, you can use ggplot's faceting functions (`facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`). You can reverse the Y axis with the `scale_y_reverse()` function.

Here's one way to go about it:

```
library(ggplot2) # Load the library

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + # Tell ggplot what you're plotting
  geom_point() + # Tell ggplot it's a scatter plot
  facet_wrap(~ ID) + # Plot one chart for each ID
  scale_y_reverse() # Reverse the axis

p # Display the chart
```

Comment: Thanks! but what if I want to only plot one of the data in reverse? perhaps I was not clear, I am looking for a unique chart for each ID, where each chart has 2 scatter plots on it, one of which has a reversed y axis...